# How can I visualize zip codes in Germany?

Tags: gratis, library, python, maps

I have data which for each German zip code which I would like to visualize.

Is there a [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) library which can visualize this?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might try on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/ or https://gis.stackexchange.com/ Although this is technically the correct site, they might have more domain knowledge over there

Comment: Your best bet is probably to convert the postal codes to points or geographic regions and then map those with e.g. GRASS.